# Post JSON data into multiple models / table from one Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am a relative newby to ASP CORE and Im trying to Post a JSON that comes from an Angular 6 Client side.

The **JSON** Looks as Follow (Please, use any JSON for formatter to visualize it):

```
{"supplier":10001,"date":"2018-09-03T20:42:29Z","summary":[{"day":"1","aliments": 
["1012","1016","1017","1013","1021","1020"]},{"day":"2","aliments": 
["1015","1019","1023","1022","1018","1014"]},{"day":"3","aliments": 
["1027","1031","1030","1026","1025","1029"]},{"day":"4","aliments": 
["1040","1039","1035","1033","1038","1036"]},{"day":"5","aliments": 
["1032","1037","1042","1043","1041","1038"]}]}
```

This information should be Inserted into 2 tables the first one is the master table which have this structure:

**Name of the model and the table is "Menu".**

**Colums:**
MenuId,
Date,
FK_Supplier

**EF Core Model:**

```
public int MenuId { get; set; }
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
public int FkSupplier { get; set; }
```

**The second one is a "menudia"  (table and Model):**

**Colums:**
MenudiaId,
FK_AlimentId,
FK_MenuId,
Dia,

**EF Core:**

```
public int? MenuDiaId { get; set; } 
public int? FkAlimentId { get; set; }
public int? FkMenuId { get; set; }
public int? Dia { get; set; }
```

I captured 2 pictures to show you how the data should be inserted in the Database:

**Menu:**

[image]

**Menudia:**

[image]

**I created 2 Models to handle the data as I need and here is the result:**

**NewMenuContent Model:**

```
public int? menuid { get; set; }
public int suplidor { get; set; }
public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
public List<MenuItems> menuresumen { get; set; }
```

**MenuItems Model:**

```
   public int Day { get; set; }

   public List<dynamic> alimentos { get; set; }
```

I already have this in my controller which successfully insert data into the Menu Table:

```
[HttpPost]
        public int  PostMenu([FromBody] NewMenuContent menu)
        {

            var newmenu = new Menu
            {
                FkSuplidorId = menu.supplier,
                Semana = menu.date,
            };
            var menuid = _context.Menu
            .Where(x => x.FkSupplierId == menu.supplier)
            .Where(x => x.date == menu.date)
            .Select(x => x.MenuId).FirstOrDefault();
            _context.Menu.Add(newmenu);


            _context.SaveChanges();
            return menuid;

        } //NOTE: "menu" is the json.
```

NOTE: Some of the variables and properties of this questions has been translated to from spanish to english, if you see any typing error, dont pay attention to it.

So How can I insert data in the menudia table as shown in the pictures above?  Please note that I would love to this in the same controller and in the same function that is posted above.

The login of this process that the user will select a range of aliments per day which will be part of a Food Menu of an specific supplier, So for example if the user select the supplier "McDonald" he will be able to select several aliments per day (monday = burger, fries, chicken nuggets, cola).

Any help on this one is much appreciated as have been on searching the web and trying a variety of different things without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Microsoft documentation may help: [Saving Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data)

> If you create several new related entities, adding one of them to the
>   context will cause the others to be added too.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blog = new Blog
    {
        Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnet",
        Posts = new List<Post>
        {
            new Post { Title = "Intro to C#" },
            new Post { Title = "Intro to VB.NET" },
            new Post { Title = "Intro to F#" }
        }
    };

    context.Blogs.Add(blog);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have written similar code and can verify that EF Core should create the related entities as you describe in your question.

There is a sample app on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/samples/core/Saving/Saving/RelatedData/).

Comment: After some research, this solution guided me to the right way!